# TeXstudio disable character shortcut (Ctrl+Alt+U)

Tags: texstudio, characters, spanish

I'm currently using an English keyboard with an "International" configuration to write in spanish. I use the shortcut <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to write "á", <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> for "é", and so on for each vowel.

In TeXstudio I have no problem with á,é,í or ó, but when I try to write the "ú" character I get a small window with characters, instead.
I've searched in the shortcuts options, looking for some action related to <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>, which is the same) but I found none.

Is there a way to disable that specific shortcut?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default `Ctrl + Alt + U` opens the tool to insert a unicode character. This keyboard shortcut can be switched off by going to

```
Options -> Configure TeXstudio... -> Shortcuts -> Menus -> Edit
```

in the English user interface. In the Spanish interface it is

```
Opciones -> Configure TeXstudio... -> Atajos -> Menús -> Editar.
```

Just delete/change the shortcut for *Insert Unicode Character...* in the column that says *Current Shortcut* or *Atajo actual* respectively. Hope this solves the problem.

[image: Configure TeXstudio dialog]