# shortcut for collapse and expand in texstudio

Tags: texstudio

How can I set the shortcut for collapse and expand for various levels in texstudio? I think this way the navigation would be much easier. For instance, I can collapse all sections and then go through them.

Comment: As one might expect: Options -> Configure TeXStudio -> Shortcuts, as mentioned in e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/262703/texstudio-disable-character-shortcut-ctrlaltu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The collapse and expand shortcuts have no default values. You can set them manually. As mentioned by Torbjørn T., the collapse and expand shortcuts can be set under:

```
Options -> Configure TeXstudio -> Shortcuts -> Menus -> View -> Collapse / Expand
```

[image: shortcuts]

---

In the following example, we have:

> Level 1: `\begin{document}`
>
> Level 2: All `\chapter{}` commands
>
> Level 3: All `\section{}` commands

So just collapse and expand the appropriate levels.

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}

\chapter{C1}
zzz
\section{C1S1}
zzz
\section{C1S2}
zzz

\chapter{C2}
zzz
\section{C2S1}
zzz
\section{C2S2}
zzz

\chapter{C3}
zzz
\section{C3S1}
zzz
\section{C3S2}
zzz

\end{document}
```